# More questions about 'to be' in japanese

Tags: grammar

I had some questions about the verb 'to be'. I know you have the copula 「だ」　and 「いる」and「ある」.
However, the copula does not have all the conjugations, so how would you express something like 'can be' or 'make be'(like in: 'I made him happy'). And use expressions like 「なければならない」would you form something like 「じゃなければならない」? Or the expression 「～たい」(Like in: 'I want to be happy'). I don't really know. I suggest maybe using 「である」. But I know that's really like literary language. Also how would you say all this with i-adjectives?

Well, Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Your question seems a little too broad to answer to, but some examples:

> - I want to be happy. -- [私]{わたし}は[幸]{しあわ}せになりたい。 [ 〜に-なる ]
> - I can be happy. -- 私は幸せになれる。 [ なれる (potential form of なる) ]
> - I made him happy. -- 私は[彼]{かれ}を幸せにした。 [ ～に-する ]
> - He has to be happy. -- 彼は幸せでなければならない。[ ～なければならない ]
> - He should be happy. -- 彼は幸せであるべきだ。[ ～べき-だ ]
> - He must be happy. (assuming) -- 彼は幸せにちがいない。[ ～に-ちがいない ]
> - He may be happy. (possibility) -- 彼は幸せかもしれない。[ ～かもしれない ]

of course there can be other translations though.

I picked a key expression (verb or auxiliary phrase) from each sentence into bracket. Recommend you should look them up in textbooks / dictionaries. Could this be of any help?

Comment: Yorokobaseta sounds more like "I made him happy" to me.  Shiawase ni shita is like "set him to happy mode" which is probably good.  Adding some examples for the ending ~saseru might be good for this question.